# SSIS Project Deployment with excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, deployment, ssis, etl

I created an SSIS project with multiple packages. One of my package has a data flow task using Excel as data source. After deploying the project to SQL SSISDB, I can see the .dtsx files in SSMS. But where should the excel file reside? Should it still be in my local machine. The SQL resides on another server and not my local machine. Where is the deployed packages stored?

Can someone explain these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Excel file

If the excel connection manager are pointing to a fixed path on your local machine. It will throw an error when executed from different server since the excel file path is not found.

You have to use [dynamic excel connections](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/dynamic-file-name-for-excel-connection-manager-ssis/) to fix this issue, or to use an excel file on a shared network location (UNC path).

#### Package deployment

After deployment, the packages are stored within SSISDB database:

- [Deploying Packages to SQL Server Integration Services Catalog (SSISDB)](https://www.sqlshack.com/deploying-packages-to-sql-server-integration-services-catalog-ssisdb/)
- [Ways to use and execute SQL Server Integration Services packages](https://www.sqlshack.com/ways-use-execute-sql-server-integration-services-packages/)
- [SSISDB for SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/ssisdb-for-sql-server-integration-services)